# How do i read in selective files (images) from a folder, where the search criteria is in a data frame? in R (Rstudio)

Tags: r

This is a sample of the data frame, i need to read in 5000 images from a folder with the file name that is stated on this data frame (Image column)... and the files are .jpg

```
Index   Image                      MEL     
 1.     ISIC_0000002                1
 2.     ISIC_0000004                1
 3.     ISIC_0000013                1
 4.     ISIC_0000022_downsampled    1
 5.     ISIC_0000026_downsampled    1
 6.     ISIC_0000029_downsampled    1
 7.     ISIC_0000030_downsampled    1
 8.     ISIC_0000031_downsampled    1
 9.     ISIC_0000035_downsampled    1
 10.    ISIC_0000036_downsampled    1
```

Comment: This may use quite a lot of memory.

Comment: Yeah i know, i tried to read in the all of the images in folder but it didnt let me because of the memory constraints, im hoping these images wont use up the images

Comment: @JCran Do you know how i would overcome the memory error, i was only able to read in 433 images but i need to read in 5000 images.... the error comes up with Error: cannot allocate vector of size 15.9 Mb

Comment: There isn't a way to get around this without getting a computer with more memory. I would suggest thinking about whether you really need to have 5000 images in Rstudio's environment at one time. Can you manipulate them one at time in a loop? I suggest editing your question to include your overall aim here, then more memory efficient ways to accomplish the task may become apparent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

where dirname is the path to the folder containing your images.

```r
library(jpeg)

Mypictures <- list()

#df$Image is a character vector of all the image names in your dataframe, which the loop will index over. Should be length 5000.

for(image in df$Image){
Mypictures[[image]] <- readJPEG(paste0("dirname", "/", image,".jpg"))
}
```

You may want to look at depending on what you want to do with the images.
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/jpeg/versions/0.1-8.1/topics/readJPEG

Comment: But will this read in every image in the folder...?, becuase i need to read in only 5000 images the folder has 70,000 images..... the data frame (the image column) has the images i need to read in....

Comment: No it will read in all the images in the dataframe. Replace df in the loop with the name of your dataframe. Use `print(length(df$Image)) to convince yourself :).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keept your dataframe you coud use:

```
df <- fs::dir_info(glob = "*.jpg") %>% 
   dplyr::mutate(Pic = purrr::map(path, ~ jpeg::readJPEG(.x)))
```